# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 install - no option

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, installation

Ok I've searched everywhere for an answer and can't seem to find an answer.

I've installed VS 2010 and with it came SQL Server 2008 Express. I am currently trying to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and it won't give me the option to install.

At first, I thought it wanted me to install SP1 first.. but it says there is nothing to patch!

My SQL patch version: 10.1.2531.0

[image: SQL Server 2008 Setup]

EDIT: This is the installer I'm using: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: What is "it"? What installer is that, and where did you get it?

Comment: Also you should consider [the latest version of Management Studio Express (2012)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34699), which now supports full SSMS functionality (RTM and previous versions have several limitations).

Comment: I added a link to the installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: What is it that you're expecting?  I would probably go with "Next".

Comment: Not sure why my answer was deleted but have a read of my blog post that walks you through installing SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/06/03/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-management-studio/. You wouldn't believe how many people have trouble with this...

Comment: @codefrenzy just FYI link-only answers are not considered "durable" - if your blog goes away tomorrow, the answer has become useless. See the [FAQ re:deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion): "barely more than a link to an external site"

Answer (score 12):

I was having the exact same problem with my installation for [SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985). Go back to the "Installation Type" step (the previous one), and closely read the text under each radio button. The option under the "New installation or add shared features" reads:

> Select this option if you want to install a new instance of SQL Server
>   **or want to install shared components such as SQL Server Management Studio or Integration Services**.

You have to select "New Installation", and not "Add Features", as counterintuitive as this may seem.

Answer (score 3):

Back up one step and choose the "Perform a new installation" option. Brilliant, I know.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip.  Thats 30 minutes of my life I'll never get back. Thanks MS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember Management Studio is not bundled with every version of SQL Serever 2008 Express installator. Maybe you could try to install this: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) or this [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985) depending on your version of server.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this glitch, too.  The Shared Features selection list should show  [✓] Management Tools - Basic.  The checkbox was auto-filled.

I rebooted, then ran the installer as an administrator and it worked as expected.